# Dynamically added jquery button does not work

Tags: jquery, html, dom, button

I have two jquery calls. The first one adds a button to the html and the second one does something if the added button is clicked. The problem is that the second one is not working at all.

The html looks like this

```
<input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add the button">
<div id="results"></div>
```

And the script file looks like this

```
$("#add_button").on('click', function () {
     $("#results").html('<input type="button" class="ok_button" value="OK">');
});
$(".ok_button").on('click', function () {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyLVa/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('#results').on('click', '.ok_button', function() { ..code here.. }
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XyLVa/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Since the `ok_button` is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:-

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#results').on('click', '.ok_button', function() {
    alert('ok'); 
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XyLVa/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#add_button").click(function() {
    $newButton = $('<input type="button" class="ok_button" value="OK">');
    $newButton.click(function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
    $("#results").append($newButton);
});
```

Working example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/cq3nm/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', "#add_button", function (){
$("#results").append('<button type="button" class="ok_button">ok</button');

});
$(document).on('click', ".ok_button", function (){
alert("i know nothing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet did not work because the event was bound to the DOM before the element was added to it. Try the following snippet :

```
$("#add_button").on('click', function () {
   $("#results").html('<input type="button" class="ok_button" value="OK">');
   $(".ok_button").off('click').on('click', function() {
       alert("ok");
   });
});
```